# Get the values from multiple models in a single view in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do I get the values from multiple models in a single view? Is using ViewModel the correct solution? Creating ParentModel also gives error. Any step-by-step tutorial on this?

Comment: What is the error? 
Read this: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/06/30/how-we-do-mvc-view-models/

Comment: I have two models (suppose First and Second). I then create a parentmodel:
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public virtual First first{ get; set; }
        public virtual Second second { get; set; }
    } In view, I have @model projectName.Models.ParentModel. I want to display attributes of both the table in this view eg.@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.first.address) But I get error like this: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies...', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'projectName.Models.ParentModel'. Any help?

Comment: Can you paste the code you where you are passing the model into the view. ?

Comment: I am new to MVC and don't have clear idea about this.. do I need to create a separate controller as well using the ParentModel? I am not even allowed to do that..(gives error).

Comment: It depends on your design. But you create a Controller and in your Controller you have a method which is an Action. The Action may be the same name as your View, and you usually do something like return View(model). If the action isn't the name of your View you will do something like View("ViewName", model);

Answer (score 1):

Create a ViewModel, Check this [Creating a View Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvc3fundamentals_topic7.aspx)